# parsing HTML as a response from an async call

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, asynchronous

I am making an async call and am getting HTML in response. The problem is when I try to set it as an element's `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` I'm getting `[object Response]`. And I guess this makes sense. But when I try to parse it, I get `[object HTMLDocument]`. Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { DictionaryMoreButton } from '../DictionaryMoreButton';
import { SearchBar } from '../SearchBar';

export const Dictionary = ({ initialData }) => {
  const [searchBarValue, setSearchBarValue] = useState('');
  const [startValue, setStartValue] = useState(0);
  const [vocabularyData, setVocabularyData] = useState(initialData);
  const getResultForItem = searchQuery => fetch(`https://learngerman.dw.com/learngerman/search?languageCode=en&item=${searchQuery}&start=${startValue}&rows=12`).then(r => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    return parser.parseFromString(r, 'text/html');
  }).catch(error => console.log(error));

  return (
    <div className="container page-container">
      <div className="section">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-12">
            <header>
              <SearchBar
                handleChange={async e => {
                  const result = await getResultForItem(e.target.value, 0);
                  console.log(result);
                  setSearchBarValue(result);
                }}
                handleKeyPress={async e => e.key.toLowerCase() === 'enter' && setVocabularyData(await getResultForItem(searchBarValue))}
              />
              <div className="section exercise-container vocabulary copy">
                <div className="vocabularies" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: vocabularyData }}/>
                <DictionaryMoreButton
                  handleClick={async () => {
                    setStartValue(startValue + 12);
                    setVocabularyData(vocabularyData + await getResultForItem(searchBarValue));
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </header>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I parse it? I run a CURL and got a loooong HTML answer so won't be posting it here, but it's valid HTML. I know I could do `res.json()` if it was JSON. Is there something like this for HTML?

Answer (score 2):

> But when I try to parse it, I get `[object HTMLDocument]`
>
> How can I parse it?

You **have** parsed it. That is why you are getting an HTML document and not a string.

> The problem is when I try to set it as an element's `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`

`dangerouslySetInnerHtml` expects you to pass it **unparsed** HTML and not a parsed DOM.

You can use [the `text` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) (where you would use the `json` method to parse JSON) to get the HTML source code from the response.